# Is this bluetooth setup good?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, bluetooth, wires

I am trying to do this tutorial http://www.instructables.com/id/Chappie-Self-Balancing-Robot/  on building a self-balancing robot with uno. However, I bothered by the Bluetooth wiring. I've done Arduino projects with Bluetooth before and all the Hc-05 wirings I've seen have it connected to the Tx and Rx pins.Currently, I have my Bluetooth module wiring like this :   with http://cdn.instructables.com/FSK/AI30/HMMFE6UO/FSKAI30HMMFE6UO.MEDIUM.jpg.
Will the different wiring need a different implementation, the code I see on the chappie instructable link does not have any pin mentions but I'm not sure. Is the chappie wiring fine? should I change my wiring? should I change my code?
I'm confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which code are you reading? At step 5 he wrote

> Complete code can be found on the [GITHUB](https://github.com/ManpreetSingh80/CHAPPIE).

The sketch file ([here is the direct link](https://github.com/ManpreetSingh80/CHAPPIE/blob/master/SelfBalance_robot0_67/SelfBalance_robot0_67.ino)) has the following lines:

```
const int rxpin = 11; // pin used to receive (not used in this version) 
const int txpin = 4; // pin used to send to LCD

SoftwareSerial blue(rxpin, txpin); // new serial port on pins 2 and 3
```

This means that the bluetooth is using a software serial on pins 11 and 4.

I don't know where you got the image you posted, but anyway that wiring is not the same as the one in the instructable. With your wiring, you can either use the software serial on pins 0 and 1, or (better) use the hardware serial. To do so, remove or comment the lines I highlighted and then replace every call to `blue` with `Serial`.